# auto.arima differencing when data is stationary

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a time series object of weekly sales values and have tested for stationarity using both KPSS test and ADF test. Both tests tell me that the data is stationary.

```
> kpss.test(salests)

    KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  salests
KPSS Level = 0.34151, Truncation lag parameter = 2, p-value = 0.1


> adf.test(salests)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  salests
Dickey-Fuller = -4.9851, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

However, when I put the timeseries through `auto.arima()`, it returns a model with d=1. Can anyone explain this? The data is weekly sales and I am using multiple regressors in the `xreg` argument.

```
> fit
Series: traints 
Regression with ARIMA(0,1,1) errors 

Coefficients:
          ma1  as.factor(proj$Brand)1  as.factor(proj$Brand)2   Bundle
      -0.9438               -167.1745                 52.8263  99.4438
s.e.   0.0296                 56.7019                 48.3095  46.7456
      as.factor(proj$Reduction)0.25  as.factor(proj$Reduction)0.33
                           177.7417                       541.3828
s.e.                        27.6599                        52.7583

sigma^2 estimated as 16570:  log likelihood=-669.62
AIC=1353.23   AICc=1354.36   BIC=1371.94
```

Comment: I mistook the p value for ADF test for the KPSS one. `auto.arima` only uses KPSS by default to specify `d`. The fact that `salests` produces a p value of 0.1 would mean that d should be zero (based on the source code). So, probably salests does not end up in that part of the auto.arima code. You would need to include a reproducible example in order to investigate more. Your data + the auto.arima code you used.